# Get all prices with $ from string into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

```
var string = 'Our Prices are $355.00 and $550, down form $999.00';
```

How can I get those 3 prices into an array?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Some other Reg-expressions, but they only found the first price.

Comment: @Ezra What? Why? Did you include the `g` flag?

Comment: I strongly vote _against_ [Data Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping).

Comment: @Xufox, nope. I have very little knowledge of regex :/

Comment: Just read the Wikipedia article: _"...Data scraping is generally considered an ad hoc, inelegant technique, often used only as a "last resort" when no other mechanism for data interchange is available. Aside from the higher programming and processing overhead, output displays intended for human consumption often change structure frequently. Humans can cope with this easily, but a computer program may report nonsense, have been told to read data in a particular format or from a particular place, and with no knowledge of how to check its results for validity..."_

Comment: @UweKeim yeah, I wish there were other ways. But like it said, "last resort". :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The RegEx

```
string.match(/\$((?:\d|\,)*\.?\d+)/g) || []
```

That `|| []` is for no matches: it gives an empty array rather than `null`.

### Matches

- `$99`
- `$.99`
- `$9.99`
- `$9,999`
- `$9,999.99`

### Explanation

```
/         # Start RegEx
\$        # $ (dollar sign)
(         # Capturing group (this is what you’re looking for)
  (?:     # Non-capturing group (these numbers or commas aren’t the only thing you’re looking for)
    \d    # Number
    |     # OR
    \,    # , (comma)
  )*      # Repeat any number of times, as many times as possible
\.?       # . (dot), repeated at most once, as many times as possible
\d+       # Number, repeated at least once, as many times as possible
)
/         # End RegEx
g         # Match all occurances (global)
```

To match numbers like `.99` more easily I made the second number mandatory (`\d+`) while making the first number (along with commas) optional (`\d*`). This means, technically, a string like `$999` is matched with the *second* number (after the optional decimal point) which doesn’t matter for the result — it’s just a technicality.

Comment: This does not get the $550 price.

Comment: Ooo, found an issue with this. Will not handle pricing with a coma e.g. $1,335.00, it will return $1

Comment: @Ezra Do you need to cover the case `$1,999` (without e. g. `.99`) as well?

Comment: well as many as possible would be preferred.  I would like $1,999.99 to work as well as $1999

Comment: @Ezra Ok, I’ve added a simple fix and also posted a full explanation of the RegEx.

Comment: Worked well for me ($1,999.90)

Answer (score 4):

A non-regex approach: split the string and filter the contents:

```
var arr = string.split(' ').filter(function(val) {return val.startsWith('$');});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `match` with `regex` as follow:

```
string.match(/\$\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/` : Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\$`: Matches `$` literal
3. `\d+`: Matches one or more digits
4. `()?`: Matches zero or more of the preceding elements
5. `\.`: Matches `.`
6. `g` : Matches all the possible matching characters

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/03q3cvmL/)

This will check if there is a **possible** decimal digits following a '$'

Comment: @Identity1 Can you explain?

Comment: @Identity1 It does. See the `demo`